# Is it legal for either a public or private workplace to require a flu vaccine (in the US)?

Tags: united-states, privacy, vaccination

Note - Disregard medical workers, direct medical workers or similar jobs.   Not looking to debate that some industries may have needs.

I see that many workplaces and universities are mandating COVID vaccine verification.   Although I don't understand the legality on this, I do understand that a "national emergency" might make it hard to debate this.   And I am not condoning the mandate, I am saying for this question on the FLU VACCINE, let's not debate the COVID vaccine.

So let's note two examples:

1. Private company/school.   No workers in medical or like field.
2. Public.   So public school, civil workers, etc.

**Edit Note:**   Because the only answer I have is so poor and does not even address what the question is asking I will add an addendum.

The question is in regards to how an employer would ever have access to tell if you had a flu shot.   I have owned a few businesses and paid for med coverage for employees.   I have almost no rights to any sort of their medical information.   What's funny is I went through a workmen's comp claim and had almost no rights to info on that employee even though they were putting a claim against my business.   So how in the hell in the past 2 years have the flood gates swung open on employers access to employee medical.   There is no way I would have been able to tell if an employee had a flu shot two years ago.

Comment: There is nothing odd or inappropriate about the strains of flu selected this year, or any other year. This is always a judgement. It tries to incorporate strains that have circulated recently both in the US and in other countries. According to the CDC: "The seasonal influenza (flu) vaccine is designed to protect against the four influenza viruses that research indicates are most likely to spread and cause illness among people during the upcoming flu season. " The final decision is made by the FDA, not by companies.

Answer (score 12):

A company can mandate getting a flu shot as a condition of employment. The government can do the same (for its employees) – Washington state *has* done so at least for covid. Some individuals qualify for a disability accommodation, so they would be exceptions (e.g. they could be moved to working away from the public). A sincere religious conviction also gives rise to a religious-accommodation exemption. [This guidance](https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/guidance/questions-and-answers-religious-discrimination-workplace) addresses the question of what constitutes a sincerely held religious belief.

Comment: There is legal precedence of this mandate being upheld in US court?    I have never heard of a company mandating a flu shot outside of the medical services fields until the past few months.

Comment: There are no special anti-vax rights under the law, that is, it's not specific to vaccinations. This follows from the employers right to impose conditions on employees while at the workplace. E.g. you can be required to wear black socks on the job. You can be required to be vaccinated while on the job. It's true, but irrelevant, that being vaccinated can't be turned on and off depending on whether you are on the job. The same with wearing a beard – an employer can require you to be clean-shaven, with religious exemptions in place.

Comment: Yea I don't think you get it.   And this is a really poor answer.   So does your company also have the right to make you wear black underwear?   Do they get to make you pull down your pants once a day to prove it?   Hmmm... thinking not.    There a privacy laws around personal health information.   I have never seen one law around requiring a person to ever disclose that they have or haven't taken a flu shot.   Yes I have seen a requirement around lethal diseases (not even sure COVID meets the past examples)... cont.

Comment: Point being is that why can't the employer require that no one have heart conditions, no one have cancer, whatever they want?    Trying to mandate a flu vaccine isn't really the "thing".   The "thing" is that an employer has no right to that information.   They are in essence asking you to wear black underwear and want you to pull down your pants once a year.    This will hit state supreme courts this year.   I wish you would delete your answer because your answer is poor, mentions COVID which I explicitly asked not to, and talks about religious exemptions - nothing to do with question.

Comment: @blankip: In the US, other than Montana, employment is generally at-will. Employees may be dismissed for any reason or for no reason, *except* for reasons which are specifically protected by law, such as race or religion. Anti-vax is not on the list.

Comment: @kevin - you don't get it.   It isn't anti-vax.  It is privacy.   And I would argue a step further here.   Can your workplace send out a survey to its employees that ask them what religion they belong to and various religious beliefs?

Comment: @blankip: Actually, they *can* send such a survey, and fire you if you refuse to fill it out. What they cannot do is go through the results and fire (say) all the Jews. However, sending out such a survey is probably not in their best legal interests because it makes it easy to accuse them of doing exactly that, so in practice they won't do it.

Comment: @Kevin - well you are wrong.    There are almost no cases at the workplace that an employer can require an employee to divulge any data around their religion.   This is a fact in the US.   You saying they can send a survey hahahahahahahahaha.   After they send that survey they will be sued to kingdom come but sure I guess in theory its "legal".    You still don't understand my question or what I was getting at.

Comment: @blankip I can imagine a lot of valid surveys that would result in identifying Jews - e.g. "please let us know which holidays you are unable to work," "we are hosting a dinner please let us know of any dietary restrictions: vegan/vegetarian/kosher," etc.

Comment: @Kevin Can employees be required to have the flu vaccine in Montana? In the United Kingdom there is statutory protection from **unfair dismissal** which is basically any dismissal which is not on reasonable grounds. Dismissal for refusing a flu vaccine would generally be unfair dismissal except in special cases where the employee was working with vulnerable people - e.g. hospital.

Comment: @Nemo: Montana is different so I didn't want to get into it, but in short, the employer is required to have "good cause" for dismissal, but the law is rather vague about what exactly counts as "good cause" (there's no list of valid reasons). I tend to imagine that "there's a pandemic, you refused to get an FDA-approved vaccine, you don't have a valid medical or religious reason for doing so, and you are now putting our customers at risk" would be good cause, but I'm no employment lawyer. As for the flu vaccine... I have no idea. Go ask someone who specializes in this.